# How many time a specific key occur in std::multimap

Tags: c++, dictionary

I'm working on multimap datatype in c++ and I want to know how many times a specific key exists in my map. The next examples will explain what I'm looking for:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main ()
{
  std::multimap<char,int> mymap;
  mymap.insert ({'c',10});
  mymap.insert ({'y',20});
  mymap.insert ({'c',30});
  mymap.insert ({'z',40});
  mymap.insert ({'c',40});


  std::cout << "mymap.size() is " << mymap.size() << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

The above code will give me the number of unique keys in my map, which is not what I'm looking for.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <map>

    int main ()
    {
      std::multimap<char,int> mymap;

      mymap.insert ({'c',10});
      mymap.insert ({'y',20});
      mymap.insert ({'c',30});
      mymap.insert ({'z',40});
      mymap.insert ({'c',40});

      std::cout << "mymap.size('c') is " << mymap.size('c') << '\n';

      return 0;
    }
```

I want a mechanism that counts how many time the key "c" is repeated in my map. A proper answer for the previous example would be 3.

Comment: A `std::map` stores *unique* keys. I think you're looking for [`std::multimap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap) (or depending on use-case [`std::unordered_multimap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multimap)).

Comment: oh, I meant std::multimap, Sorry for that!

Comment: Then read the linked reference(s) and you should find the answer pretty quickly. And please update the question (both body and title) to reflect what you *really* mean. :)

Comment: `mymap.upper_bound(c) - mymap.lower_bound(c)`

Comment: does no-one read documentation any more? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap

Comment: thanks a lot guys, you made it very easy. I feel dump now.

Comment: @RichardHodges I was mistaken between `map` and `multimap`. This what makes the confusion. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mymap.count('c')`. Use `equal_range` method if you want to iterate over the elements with the same key.

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::equal_range(key)` to get iterators for the range and `std::distance` to find the count.

Answer (score 1):

The original question was using a map. As suggested by Some programmer dude, it is changed to multimap.

As far as I remember, multimap doesn't have a [] operator.

So change the [] operations to `insert` functions, and use the `count` function would directly get what you want. The other answers suggested `equal_range` and `upper_bound - lower_bound` are also fine.

Comment: The insertion method has been modified. Thanks for drag my attention to that!